# How do I determine which version of glibc supports the functions I use?

Tags: c++, glibc

Some functions like pthread_setname_np, the manual will say that [it was supported from glibc 2.12](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html). But for some other functions, like [pthread_self](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html), the manual doesn't say which version it has been supported.
How do I determine which version of glibc supports the functions I use ?

I tried to find information from [glibc doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/documentation.html), but I can't find anything useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Notice how, when you click through the doc link to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/), it shows a list of versions? Did you try checking the manual for the version you want to know about, to see whether it lists the function you're interested in? If you're just trying to do history - did you try checking all the manuals, to see when the function starts showing up in the listing? Did you try using a search engine to see whether other people have answered this question for specific functions?

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume pthread_self has been there since the beginning of pthreads

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sure, I did try to find which version of glibc supports pthread_self from glibc doc or google search engine, but I can't find out. I think the answer by LITzman is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the `CONFORMING TO` section in the documentation.

A function like `pthread_self` is conforming to the POSIX standard, which means that it's probably going to be available in every version of glibc.

`pthread_setname_np` Isn't defined in POSIX, but is a later addition to the library, so it says what version it's available from.

AFAIK only functions that are not defined in POSIX were added in a late version of glibc, and it usually says in the docs what version they are available from.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `man pthread_setname_np` you can see a section like this

```
VERSIONS
       These functions first appeared in glibc in version 2.12.
```

Alternatively you can query `libpthread` for the versions stored

```
$ readelf -a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so | grep pthread_setname_np
   188: 0000000000015580   293 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 pthread_setname_np@@GLIBC_2.12
   639: 0000000000015580   293 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 pthread_setname_np
```